# Tracking down which dependency contains SSE instructions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sse

One of our customers needs a build of our program without SSE as he's on quite old hardware. My problem is that even if I modify our project settings across the board to unset SSE for all libraries & binaries it would seem there's still a dependency somewhere which is compiled with SSE instructions on, causing the application to crash.

My questions is: Is there a way to take a binary or library and detect if it contains SSE instructions of a specific version of SSE or not?

We're using VS and the language is C++, so any tool applicable to that toolset would be terrific.

Comment: Why can't you find out in which library it crashes?

Comment: We link statically with all our libraries, probably should've mentioned that.

Comment: you still should mention it by editing it into your question.

Comment: And what about libraries that check for opcode availability before using them ? Just checking SSE instructions presence will flag them wrongly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disassemble all involved binaries, then do a search for SSE instruction mnemonics in the disassemblies.

Comment: Sounds like a decent last resort, would be terrific if there was an existing tool which could do the heavy lifting.

Comment: The command line and a good shell are your friend. In a Unix environment you could do it by 'for f in LIST_OF_BINARIES; do objdump -d $f > $f.S ; done; grep -e SSE_MENOMONIC_REGEXP *.S'

Comment: VS doesn't run on Unix. In Windows, it would be `for %f in (*.obj) do dumpbin /disasm:nobytes %f >> disasm.txt`. It's hard to find an SSE instruction by regexp; the naming isn't consistent.

Comment: @MSalters: I well, VS2010 does work with WINE, but I was thinking along installing Cygwin or MinGW/MinSys. Also You can use a RegExp if you just put all those mnemonics in a option list, something like '(MOV(APS|UPS|LPS|HPS|LHPS|HLPS))|(AND[N]|[X]OR)PS)...'

Comment: Plain Windows has `findstr`, you don't need grep for regexp. And wouldn't it be easier to factor out the `PS` in that regexp, i.e. `(MOV(A|U|LH?|HL?))|(ANDN?|X?OR))PS` ?

Comment: Isn't it simpler to grep for the registers ? any SSE instruction would require an xmm register.

Comment: @Bahbar: Sounds reasonable, but I'm not sure if it's 100% correct. Aren't the `PREFETCH*` and `*FENCE` instructions exceptions?

Comment: @MSalters: you're right. It does not alleviate to check some opcodes. Still, it captures most :).

Comment: [Script for analyzing CPU extensions used](http://dev.gentoo.org/%7Edirtyepic/bin/analyze-x86) -- uses perl + objdump, and some other unix junk, but it's got a good list of instruction mnemonics to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already turned off the SSE instruction generation in the compiler, the problem is in one of the static libraries. To narrow it down, basically you have 2 ways go:

1. Disassemble the .lib or .obj files you are linking to. It is not actually an easy solution unless you happen to have access to specialized tools. Generally, disassembly is a very complex process since the tool has to figure out all the execution paths in the code without actually running it. It does it to separate the data from the code. The best tool for such tasks is [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/). After disassembly you can search for the SSE instructions either by writing a macro inside IDA Pro or exporting the results to text files and just using grep.
2. A simpler approach is to run the program and find out where it crashes. You'll need two things to continue: finding out the address of the instruction that causes the crash and a "map file" to find out where it belongs to. The latter is simple: in Visual studio, you have to set the compiler AND the linker debug options to generate a map file. This file will basically tell you the address of all and every function in the executable file. Finding the crash address is usually easy as Windows will prompt you and says something like *Application error The instruction
   at "0x635de077"...*. You use that address and look at the map file to see in which function it belongs. Alternatively, you can run the program inside a debugger. When program crashes, the debugger shows you where program has stopped.

edit: Another method to get a disassembly of a .lib files is to use the [DUMPBIN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) utility that comes with Visual Studio. Also, the minidump method suggested by STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED is an excellent idea.

Comment: I'm a great fan (and customer) of IDA Pro, but I think it's overkill for the task at hand. Any half-way sophisticated diassembler library will do. Also I like your second approach better as it will yield a more accurate result in less time. +1 for that.

Comment: Actually to add to point 2: it would also be possible to take a minidump when it crashes (even at the customer site) and then analyze the minidump to see that. I.e. post-mortem which is better suited.

Comment: Yes, the first solution is truly n overkill. I just mentioned it since the other answer just briefly suggested that. Although IDA Pro used to have free version that might be enough for this task. In general, it is good for programmers who deal with low-level code to get used to look at the disassembly of their code.

Comment: The minidump is an excellent idea. He probably would not like to ask the customer to run a debugger! Still, maybe just a screenshot with the Windows crash dialogbox is all the customer needs to capture.

Comment: @AlefSin: they still have a free version. Current Freeware version is at 5.0. However, it used to only disassemble 32bit PE files. Not sure it also handles LIB/COFF files.

Comment: Good to know. It has been a long time since I used the free version so I'm not sure which file formats it supports but as far as I remember it did support .lib and .obj files. Btw, I could not direct my comments directly to you as I don't see your user ID (all I see is STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED). Maybe my rep is just too low yet.

Comment: @AlefSin: `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` is my user ID ;)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Yeah I realized that. If the objective to select that id was to catch noobs like me, I have to say mission accomplished ;)

Comment: @AlefSin: hehe, no. It was more out of a certain affection for NT internals. It's one of the native error codes in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use a method as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx) in order to get a minidump file from the customer. I.e. have the customer run your build. Once it crashes a minidump file should be created and you can use it - post-mortem - to analyze exactly where it crashed. Which, together with the debug symbols (and/or map file), will actually tell you the exact library that caused havoc.

It boils down to point 2 in the solution suggested by AlefSin. However, the customer will not have to run a debugger. For kernel mode drivers this is usually even the only means to get meaningful information about problems. The same facility exists for user mode code, though. Use it.